# GROUP BY Syntax Mysql - Leaving out a groupable column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have Table A with columns X,Y,Z.

X is an FK, Y is a description. Each X has exactly one corresponding Y. So if X stays the same over multiple records, Y stays the same too. 
So there may be any number of records where X and Y are the same.

Now I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT X, Y
FROM A
GROUP BY X;
```

Will this query work?
Y is supposed to be grouped alongside X, but I didnt explicitely specify it in the query.
Does MySQL still implicitely act this way though? And is this behavior reliable/standardized?
Furthermore, will the results vary based on the datatype of Y. For example, is there a difference if Y is either VARCHAR, CHAR or INT? In case of an int, will the result be a SUM() of the grouped records?

Is the behavior MySQL will expose in such a case normed/standardized and where can I look it up?

Comment: reliable/standardized - I wouldn't like to rely on hope that all mysql implementations are the same and that mariadb is always in step with mysql (I mention mariadb since I know that some sites have a mix of mysql and mariadb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each `X` has exactly one corresponding `Y`
>
> `SELECT X, Y FROM A GROUP BY X;`
>
> Will this query work?

Technically, what happens when you run this query under MySQL depends on wether sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled or not:

- it it is enabled, the query errors: all non-aggregated columns must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (you need to add `Y` to the `GROUP BY` clause)
- else, the query executes, and gives you an *arbitrary* value of `Y` for each `X`; but since `Y` is *functionnaly dependant* on `X`, the value is actually predictable, so this is OK.

Generally, although the SQL standard does recognizes the notion of functionnaly-dependant column, it is a good practice to always include all non-aggregated colums in the `GROUP BY` clause. It is also a requirement in most databases other than MySQL (and, starting MySQL 5.7, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled by default). This also prevents you from various pitfalls and unpredictable behaviors.

Using `ANY_VALUE()` makes the query both valid and explicit about its purpose:

```
SELECT X, ANY_VALUE(Y) FROM A GROUP BY X;
```

Note that if you only want the distinct combinations of `X, Y`, it is simpler to use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X, Y FROM A;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Just to make sure I understand the term "non-aggregated column" correctly: 
In my query, Y is a non-aggregated column because I did not use a function for aggregation on it like SUM(Y) or COUNT(Y). Is that correct? Any Column in my SELECT statement to which I havent applied such functions are therefore "non-aggregated columns" in terms of the official docs?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will work if `Y` is functionally dependent on `X` (depending on SQL mode being used), but if you are trying to get distinct X,Y pairs from the table, it is better to use `DISTINCT`. The GROUP BY is meant to be used with the aggregate functions.

So you should use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X, Y
FROM A;
```

A sample case where you would use `GROUP BY` would be with an aggregate functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X, Y, COUNT(*)
FROM A
GROUP BY  X, Y;
```